# "return" seems to return old variable values

Tags: java, return-value

I have a question regarding this

```
public class Palindrom
{
  public static boolean isPalindrom(String text)
  {
    boolean back = true; //return variable
    text = text.replaceAll("\\s","");

    //checking special cases - text.length() = 0 or 1
    if (text.length() <= 1)
    {
      if (text.length() == 0)
      {
        System.out.println("An empty string cannot be a palindrom");
        back = false;
      }
      else
      {
        //checking if the single String-element is a letter
        if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(0)) == true)
        {
          System.out.println("An single-character string - given that it is a valid word - is always a palindrom");
          back = true;
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("The String contains something that isn't a letter 1");
          back = false;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      text = text.toLowerCase();

      //now we always have to check if the first and last element are letters and if they're equal
      if ((Character.isLetter(text.charAt(0)) && Character.isLetter(text.charAt(text.length() - 1))) == true)
      {
        //TEST
        //System.out.println("Checks if letters");

        if (text.charAt(0) == text.charAt(text.length() - 1)) 
        {
          back = true;

          //now we have to the recursive calling
          text = text.substring(1,text.length() - 1);

          //if the cut String has a length = 0, then there is no need to call the method again
          if (text.length() != 0)
          {
            //TEST
            System.out.println("Calls the method again");

            Palindrom.isPalindrom(text);
          }
          //else: we're finished
        }
        else
        {
          back = false;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("The String contains something that isn't a letter 2");
        back = false;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("four");
    System.out.println("back is : " + back);
    System.out.println("five");

    return back;
  }
}
```

Now if I call the method with e.g. "adba" as text then I get this as console output:

```
Calls the method again
four
back is : false
five
four
back is : true
five
true
```

But thing is "*System.out.println("back is : " + back)*" is only called once and the return value seems to change back to the previous one.
Any ideas what to do about that?

Comment: Your method is calling itself.  Each invocation has its own local `back` variable.  It's not "changing back" to a previous value, you literally have more than one `back` variable; one for each call to `isPalindrom`

Comment: You could create a global variable `back` and use that instead

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a requirement(I mean, unless you are trying to learn recursion) to write your own algorithm, the following standard library will solve the problem:

```
public boolean isPlanidrom(String planidrom) {
    StringBuilder original = new StringBuilder(planidrom);
    String reverse = original.reverse().toString();
    return planidrom.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse);
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(isPlanidrom("Madam"));
System.out.println(isPlanidrom("hello olleh"));
```

will print:

```
true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign recursive call result to outer call

try changing

```
Palindrom.isPalindrom(text);
```

to

```
back= Palindrom.isPalindrom(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this line

```
Palindrom.isPalindrom(text);
```

to this line

```
back= Palindrom.isPalindrom(text);
```

Reason: because your code line does not store the value of back and calls itself. Save the value of back into back variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're calling this method recursively, and the method itself is printing out the result, which is bad design.  If you want to pass arguments to this method and call it from the command line, you need to put all the System.out.println()s into a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("four");
    System.out.println("back is : " + Palindrom.isPalindrom(args[0]) );
    System.out.println("five");
}
```

This way, the recursive method isn't running all those print statements every time it gets called.  The other move will be to change line 54 from

```
Palindrom.isPalindrom(text);
```

to

```
back =  back && Palindrom.isPalindrom(text);
```

EDIT:  Do not simply write

```
back = Palindrom.isPalindrom(text);
```

This will just get you the value of the most recent call to the method, not a value for all of the calls ANDed together.

Now you compile your class and call

```
java Palindrom "racecar"
```

from the command line and you should see the result you're expecting:

> four
>
> Calls the method again
>
> Calls the method again
>
> Calls the method again
>
> An single-character string - given that it is a valid word - is always a palindrom
>
> back is : true
>
> five

That should get you where you need to go!

**NB:  If you're submitting this as a code exercise for school or an employer you should know that a word that is spelled the same forwards and backwards is called a "Palindrome", but the spelling isn't going to affect the performance of your code.**